# Trigger an 'onClick' via URL, but do not visit that URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, redirect

Trying to launch a click event of `.register-btn a` nav item when visiting a given URL, but not allow the browser to visit that URL.

So, **home.com/memberlogin** would remain on **home.com** *( or redirect to home.com if I must* ), and proceed to activate the click of a button.

This is what I have so far, which redirects nowhere as that ended up taking longer than the click event, and it also was quite messy having to load the 404, then wait, then redirect, then wait, then wait for the click event.

I would like something clean and smooth if possible.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(function() {
        switch (window.location.pathname) {
            case '/memberlogin':
            jQuery('.register-btn a').trigger( "click" );
    return False;
        }
      });
});
```

Probably explained it dreadfully so apologies all - the `.register-btn a` already exists so I can't create this element, I simply wish to trigger the click for it when visiting a URL/link. Open to suggestions but I assumed something like /memberlogin would suffice, then the link would trigger. The snag is I don't want to "visit" that URL, but use it for the trigger only.

Open to an easier way and tell me if I am asking for something that doesn't work, just figured there must be a way.

Comment: `jQuery(".register-btn a').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`? I'm not really getting why you would trigger a click on an anchor without allowing that to actually act as how it is intended to. in any case, preventing the default actions of these buttons should be enough (add that piece of code before triggering). Can you please briefly explain us what is exactly the expected goal? just preventing anchors to actually do their jobs? (redirect in this case)

Comment: Thanks for swift response dude. Sorry, no. In a nutshell, I would like to trigger a click event (register-btn a) but not trigger the URL location as it doesn't exist (it would 404) stay on the home URL but fire the click event. Essentially use a link to trigger a button click event? It sounds complicated, but I have been asked to provide a URL for a particular area of a site accessible only via click currently, so I would like this to click automatically but not visit the URL if possible :/

Comment: Well, if you need to point to a "fake" address you can simply set its href to "#", it will point nowhere, while if you need to make it to point to a specific div (let's say a div whose ID is test, for instance), you can set "#test" as its href. Anyway, the cleverest solution to your problem is change your `<a href="/memberlogin">anchor</a>` to `<a href="#">anchor</a>`, else you can also prevent its default action (check my comment above or the first answer below ;D)

Comment: Thank you mate. I did try # actually and happy to go with that, it didn't seem to trigger the click event when I changed it to # though :(

Comment: it will trigger, but it won't do anything at all unless an event handler is correctly binded to the anchor. In this way you won't change the URL at all, while if you want to change the url by not redirecting, just use preventDefault ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full javascript solution is (snippet updated as asked):

```js
window.onload = function () {
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dontGo')).forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(e.target.textContent);
    }, false);
  });

  
  // in order to target a specific URL you may write code like in reported,
  // assuming the result is only one element,
  // otherwise you need to use the previous [].slice.call(documen.....:
  document.querySelectorAll('.dontGo[href="linkedin.com"]')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Linkedin anchor: ' +  e.target.textContent);
  }, false);
};
```

```html
<a href="stackoverflow.com" class="dontGo"> stackoverflow </a><br/>
<a href="google.com" class="dontGo"> google </a><br/>
<a href="linkedin.com" class="dontGo"> linkedin </a><br/>
<a href="twitter.com" class="dontGo"> twitter </a><br/>
```

The [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) let you select elements in a lot of different ways:
if you need to select an anchor with a specific href value you can write:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dontGo[href="linkedin.com"]')
```

Remember, always, that the result of querySelectorAll is a NodeList array. You can test against the length of such array in order to get, just for instance, only the second element if it exists, like:

```
 var nodEles = document.querySelectorAll('.dontGo[href="linkedin.com"]');
    if (nodEles.length > 1) {
        nodEles[1]......
 }
```

or you can use the format:

```
[].slice.call(...).forEach(....
```

to convert the NodeList to a normal array and than apply the event listener for each element.

Yes, you may prefix the href attribute of [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag with an hash (#) to avoid page redirecting. But, in this case, the hash tag is used to jump in another page section and this will change your url.

Comment: Looks great, thanks :) How would I target a specific URL using this?

Comment: As mentioned above by @briosheje using a # might be simplest to avoid a 404 from the url destination and the page trying to load an actual URL

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried e.preventDefault() ?

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com" class="dontGo"> click </a>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('.dontGo').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do stuff
})
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9x7x4m6/

docs: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` ... Not `e.preventDefault`, preventDefault is a method, not a property :P (it's correct in the fiddle though!)

Comment: Not quite what I was after but still very helpul, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a function

```
function theAction(){
      return false;
 }
```

Then your link will be

```
<a href="/memberlogin" onClick="theAction()">page name </a>
```

Comment: Makes sense to make that link trigger permanently, and if I can alter the link. I was really trying to trigger a preexisting button on page URL load and not edit it at all :)